# Loading data from API to file and then import it

Tags: node.js, api

I want to load some credentials from an `API` into a `Node.js` application, and then use them whenever necessary.

Currently there is a file that stores some information and accesses the credentials directly from the environment variables and exports everything. This file is then imported whenever necessary, something like this:

`creds.js`

```
module.exports = {
    key: process.env.KEY || diqndwqn,
    id: process.env.ID || dqw2231qzaxc,
    db: {
        user: dqdwmkovvoij,
        pw: ofo9v8#$w
    }

}
```

What I want is to do a call to an API from where I retrieve these values, where the values can still be imported after but the call is only made once at the start. A solution I can imagine is doing something like a singleton where you only do the API call the first time. I know I could also export a promise but I do not want to request the credentials several times, only one time when the server runs. Any clean alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a simple class with a populate() function and getters and export it as a singleton.

```js
class MyCreds {
  constructor() {
    this.key = null;
    this.id = null;
    this.db = { user: null, pw: null }
  }
  async populate() {
    let creds = await whatever();
    this.key = cred.key;
    this.id = creds.id;
    this.db.user = creds.user;
    this.db.pw = creds.pw;
  }
}

const myCreds = new MyCreds();
module.exports = myCreds;
```

Then at the very beginning of your process you populate with `await require('my-creds').populate()` and access everywhere else the same you currently are, with `require('my-creds').id`.